# Ionic V1 - Angularjs Checkbox auto populate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to have a checkbox 'tick' its self depending on if the value data.notification is either true or false. I can see the variable is set in the console.log as true, however even with the data.model / checked it still doesn't work
Here is my controller

```html
.controller('ConfigCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,$http,$timeout,$localStorage,StorageService) {
    $scope.data = {};    
    // Declare localStorage Variables to scope variables 
    $scope.data.claymore_api= window.localStorage.getItem('claymore_api');
    $scope.data.cam_api= window.localStorage.getItem('cam_api');
    $scope.data.rpi_api= window.localStorage.getItem('rpi_api');
    $scope.data.fire_api= window.localStorage.getItem('fire_api');

    $scope.data.notification= window.localStorage.getItem('notification');
    $scope.data.enable_cam= window.localStorage.getItem('enable_cam');
    $scope.data.enable_power= window.localStorage.getItem('enable_power');
    $scope.data.enable_fire= window.localStorage.getItem('enable_fire');
    $scope.data.casefire= window.localStorage.getItem('casefire');
console.log($scope.data.notification);
      $scope.add = function () {
        window.localStorage.setItem('claymore_api',$scope.data.claymore_api);
        window.localStorage.setItem('cam_api',$scope.data.cam_api);
        window.localStorage.setItem('rpi_api',$scope.data.rpi_api);
        window.localStorage.setItem('fire_api',$scope.data.fire_api);
      };

      $scope.settings = function () {
        window.localStorage.setItem('notification',$scope.data.notification);
        window.localStorage.setItem('enable_cam',$scope.data.enable_cam);
        window.localStorage.setItem('enable_power',$scope.data.enable_power);
        window.localStorage.setItem('enable_fire',$scope.data.enable_fire);
        window.localStorage.setItem('casefire',$scope.data.casefire);
        console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('notification'));
      };      
})
```

Here is the html

```html
  <li class="item item-toggle">
     Notifications
     <label class="toggle toggle-positive">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.notification" checked="{{data.notification}}">
       <div class="track">
         <div class="handle"></div>
       </div>
     </label>
  </li>
```

Comment: Which of the console.log calls shows trooish value - the 1st one or the one in the settings function? Is the 'notification' value stored in the localStorage prior the controller initialization?

Comment: The first one console.log($scope.data.notification);

Comment: If you use `ion-checkbox`, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36528293/8555393) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35035953/8555393)?

Comment: think the value should be 1 or 0 not true false, *but i am not sure*

Comment: Solved it don't worry - With true/false